# Show results of query in a different blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

Originally I tried to show the results in a modal, but change it to show the result in a different blade. I want to retrieve all the comments made to a post using its post_id. But I am getting the following error:
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

The blade from where I am getting my post_id after clicking All Comments:

```
<section class="row posts">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset">
            <header><h3>other posts</h3></header>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article class="post">
                <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
                <div class="info">Posted by {{ $post->user->username }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</div>
                <div class="interaction">
                    <a href="#" class="like" id="like" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? 'Liked' : 'Like' }}</a> |
                    <a href="#" class="comment" id="comment" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">Comment</a> |
                    <a href="{{ route('show.comments',['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="allcomments" id="allcomments" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">All Comments</a>
                    @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                        <a href="#" class="edit" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </article>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </section>
```

The route:

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function()
{
Route::post('/showcomment/{post_id}',[
        'uses' => 'CommentController@getComments',
        'as' => 'show.comments',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
}
```

The Controller:

```
public function getComment($post_id)
    {
        $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        return view('showcomments',['comments' => $comments]);
    }
```

The blade where I want to output the result:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <section class="row posts">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset">
            <header><h3>other Comments</h3></header>
            @foreach($comments as $comment)
                <article class="comment">
                    <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                    <div class="info">Made by {{ $comment->user->username }} on {{ $comment->created_at }}</div>
                    <div class="interaction">
                        @if(Auth::user() == $comment->user)
                            |
                            <a href="#" class="edit" data-commentid="{{ $comment->id }}">Edit</a> |
                            <!--copy delete from post here including the modal-->
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

Comment: can you do `dd($comments)` to see if you are getting data?

Comment: For your view, try `return View::make('commentboard')->with('comments', $comments);` and for your route: `Route::get('/commentboard', 'CommentController@getComment')->name('commentboard');`

Comment: @AdityaThakur I made some changes to the route and added my query to PostController. Now I can see all the comments including the ones that are not associated with a given post. I need to get the unique postId. I am not sure how to do that from another controller.

Comment: @AmartyaBarua, you can pass the postid from your view to your controller using route parameter.

Comment: @AdityaThakur Tried to follow your suggestion. Updated code above. Thanks!

Comment: @AmartyaBarua is it working now?

Comment: From what I a getting, get is indeed not supported, just as the error states, your route posts to a post request

Comment: @Johhn Thanks! The suggestions solved the problem. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Aditya Thakur Thanks! The suggestions solved the problem. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this would be my approach:

```
Route::get("/posts/{post_id}/comments", "PostsController@getComments");
```

Controller:

```
// get comments...
public function getComments ($postId) {
    $comments = Post::findOrFail($postId)->comments;

   return view('showcomments',['comments' => $comments];
}
```

For the above to work: you should have already defined the post comment relationship in this case in the post model:

```
// Post Model: a post has many comments

public function comments () {
   return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'post_id');
}
```